# Adding <!Doctype> to existing xml using python

Tags: python, xml, tree

Im new to python so bear with me .. I have exisiting xml with element and tags i need to add  element , i tried with element tree , writing file with tree.write with append (it is overwriting it or its showing as textfile  ). Something isnot working .
xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<Profile>
<FILENAME>cell.xml</FILENAME>
-<PROFILE_INCIDENT>
<SOFTWARE_REV> </SOFTWARE_REV>
```

rev

desired xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Profile>
-<Profile>
<FILENAME>cell.xml</FILENAME>
-<PROFILE_INCIDENT>
<SOFTWARE_REV> </SOFTWARE_REV>
```

rev

---

Comment: forgot to add, im using Python

Comment: Well, you have to post the code you wrote. How to you think someone could help you without knowing what produces this XML?